# Need to join two tables on date range in hive for disc rate on transactions for prod catg at acc_no level monthly

Tags: hive, hiveql

- I have mapping table `mapping_table` with column: discount rate value based on prod_catg on `tot_bill` by account number  for 3 different product categories
  for group of consumer and business.
- I have one transaction table `txn` having monthly transactions for multiple acc_no on 1 day of every month (eg.txn_date: 2019-01-01).
- Table `txn` with columns `txn_date`, `acc_no`, `prod_catg`, `card_grp`, and `tot_bill(in $)` as shown in below  table with dummy values.

I need a Hive query to calculate `total_disc_amount` for each acc_no monthly at `card_no` level for `card_catg` wise for all `product_hieracy` for a year range: prod_serv_name as `x` for 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-31 and prod_serv_name as `y` for platinum category and year 2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31.

Join table on date range in hive on prod_catg and get disc_rate value to calculate tot_disc_bill (tot_bill*disc_rate) for at acc_no level monthly.

| txn_date | card_no | prod_catg | card_grp | tot_bill |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 201 | Platinum | Consumer | 900 |
| 2019-02-01 | 201 | platinum | Consumer | 500 |
| 2019-03-01 | 201 | Platinum | Consumer | 300 |
| 2020-02-01 | 201 | Platinum | Consumer | 400 |
| 2020-03-01 | 201 | Platinum | Consumer | 800 |
| 2020-03-01 | 202 | Gold | Business | 700 |
| 2020-01-01 | 203 | Gold | Business | 900 |
| 2018-10-01 | 204 | Gold | Business | 900 |
| 2018-09-01 | 205 | Platinum | Business | 100 |
| 2018-03-01 | 206 | Bronze | Business | 200 |

| prod_serv_name | prod_catg | card_grp | disc_rate | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | Platinum | Consumer | 2.5 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| x | Gold | Consumer | 2.5 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| x | Bronze | Consumer | 2.5 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| x | Platinum | Consumer | 2.5 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| x | Gold | Consumer | 3 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| x | Bronze | Consumer | 3 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| x | Gold | Business | 3 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| y | Gold | Business | 3 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |
| y | Platinum | Business | 3 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |
| y | Bronze | Business | 3 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |

Comment: i tried with hive query,  select  txn_date, MONTH(a.txn_date) month, acc_no, a.prod_catg, a.card_grp, b.prod_serv_name, tot_bill, CASE  When acc_no >= start_date AND acc_no <= end_date  Then tot_bill * b.disc_rate When acc_no >= start_date AND acc_no <= end_date AND b.prod_catg = 'Platinum' Then b.disc_rate end bill_disc from txn a left outer join  mapping_table b ON (a.prod_catg = b.prod_catg)

Comment: "its giving all rows from mapping table for acc_no , instead i want only rows with disc_rate which match report_dt between given start_date and end_date" .
Anyone please suggest , how to build the hive query.